# How to print a sentence pulling information from a dictionary that has a list inside

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary. If I want to print the output such as the following, how should I write it in python?

```
John is 20 years old with GPA 3.3.   
Shannon is 21 years old with GPA 3.4.
Eileen is 20 years old with GPA 3.5.
```

```
students = {
    101: ["John", 20, 3.3],
    102: ["Shannon", 21, 3.4],
    103: ["Eileen", 20, 3.5]
}
```

Comment: Look up `.values()`, `for .. in` loops, and f-strings.

Comment: Have you given it a try yourself? If so please post your tried code in your answer. Explain what went wrong.

Comment: Your question is very basic and you're not showing us what you tried yourself, that's generally not a good way to get an answer on StackOverflow. Share what you found and tried, and if you expected that to work, what happened instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution

```
students = {
    101: ["John", 20, 3.3],
    102: ["Shannon", 21, 3.4],
    103: ["Eileen", 20, 3.5]
}
for i in students.values():
    print(i[0]+" "+str(i[1])+" years old with GPA "+str(i[2]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate the help. I am in the process of learning python and it helps a lot.

Comment: If you notice , the dictionary has a list inside. For the result you want to iterate over each value of dict and then iterate over each value in list to get the result. Break is to ensure , its not repeated multiple times with cross results.

Comment: Notice that you don’t use `j` and the “loop” never loops. That loop has no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
for data in students.values():
    print(data[0], "is ", data[1], "years old with GPA ", data[2])
```